# stripe_event 404 error for test data, figuring out how to add stripe-account-header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe-connect

I'm using stripe to verify a profile before any transactions happen, so I want to see webhooks that have type `account.updated` and check the `verification.status`.

Im receiving a `404 error '(Status 404) (Request req_AwRiJSFxaOn1Jq) No such event: evt_1AaW9jFzjmmh0zTvsNSlfDLv`

I realize that i need a stripe account header for the specific account that the webhook is being made for. I cant figure out how to add an account header to my stripe.rb code. I saved the `stripe_account_id` in the database on account creation so i can pull that id out from the database. The part that confuses me is when the webhook sends to my app the account_id is in the webhook, so it seems I have to pull that part out of the webhook and paste into stripe.rb `{:stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}`. how is this possible?

This is the webhook that was sent from stripe in console (this is test data so i dont mind that people can see this cause its getting deleted soon anyways)

[image]

[image]

stripe.rb

```rails
require 'stripe'
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"],
    :secret_key => ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
}

Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]


StripeEvent.configure do |events|
  events.all do |event|
    # target specific events here
puts "this is working so far"
    if event.type == 'account.updated'
  account_event = event.data.object
  puts "account updated working"
  puts "#{account_event}"

end

  end
end
```

I received the webhook in stripe connected account dashboard and my app console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're likely missing the Stripe-Account header, so it's trying to fetch the Event from your Account, rather than from [the Stripe Account in which it exists](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header).

EDIT: Sorry, I totally misunderstood your question.  I think you need to [configure the StripeEvent receiver to use the Stripe Account](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event/blob/master/README.md#configuration).

Comment: I see that account headers are on requests like making a charge or refund. however Im receiving the webhook before I know which account it is for. In my database i save the `stripe_account_id` for each user on stripe custom account creation. So in my stripe.rb code how do I add an account header as `{:stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}`. The webhook has the information on who it belongs too so i would have to pull that out of the webhook before i add the header initially. am I right about that? how is that possible??

Comment: @Michael Lombardo Apologies; I misunderstood.  See my edit.